# Update command not throwing any errors, but not working either

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Update button executes the OnClick="UpdateLogo", but nothing shows up in my database. I know it executes because I can put any other instruction like refresh or redirect to another page, and it executes, it just doesn't update. I tried using the CommandName property instead of the OnClick property, but no luck there either. Any thoughts as to why?

I've moved it in and out of an `UpdatePanel` and you can see that I've got it inside a `FormView` right now. I've tried with the couple of variations on the variables like `@Atty_ID` or `?`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel19" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="ChamberLogoDataSource" runat="server" 
                          DataFile="~/App_Data/Attorneys.mdb" 
                          SelectCommand="SELECT ATTORNEYS.CHAMBER FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ATTY_ID = ?"
                          UpdateCommand="UPDATE ATTORNEYS SET CHAMBER = ? WHERE ATT_ID = ?">
                          <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ATTY_ID" QueryStringField="ATT_ID" />
                          </SelectParameters>
                          <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CHAMBER" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ATTY_ID" />
                          </UpdateParameters>
                        </asp:AccessDataSource>

                        <asp:FormView ID="FormView3" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="ChamberLogoDataSource" DefaultMode="Edit">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                Add a Chambers logo:<br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="50" Text='<%# Bind("CHAMBER") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:Button ID="UpdateChambersLogoButton" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateLogo" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:FormView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
Protected Sub UpdateLogo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ChamberLogoDataSource.Update()
End Sub
```

If I go to a certain record in the database that already has a value for `CHAMBER`, it shows up in the textbox like it should. But if it is blank and I put something in there and click the button, it doesn't get updated. If I change the text that is already there and click the button, nothing updates either. I'm kinda lost on this one, especially since there is very similar code elsewhere on this page.

Comment: Have you tried Firebug to see if it's firing an ajax error that perhaps you're not seeing?

Comment: Maybe `AutoPostBack = true` ?

Comment: Not Autopostback. When I click the update button, I don't see anything in Firebug telling me anything. Where would I look?